# mypy via pre-commit - Duplicate module name 'package.module.py' (and 'package\module.py')

Tags: python, mypy, pre-commit, pre-commit.com

I have the following repo-structure

```
my-repo/
    .github/
        linters/
            .mypy.ini
    .pre-commit-config.yaml
    mypackage/
        __init__.py
        main.py
        subpackage/
            __init__.py
            foo.py
    tests/
        conftest.py
```

When I run mypy via pre-commit `pre-commit run --all-files` I get the following error

```
mypackage\__init__.py: error: Duplicate module named "mypackage" (also at "mypackage\__init__.py")
mypackage\__init__.py: note: See https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/running_mypy.html#mapping-file-paths-to-modules for more info
mypackage\__init__.py: note: Common resolutions include: a) using `--exclude` to avoid checking one of them, b) adding `__init__.py` somewhere, c) using `--explicit-package-bases` or adjusting MYPYPATH
Found 1 error in 1 file (errors prevented further checking)
```

This is the pre-commit config I use

```
repos:
-   repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/mirrors-mypy
    rev: v1.3.0
    hooks:
    -   id: mypy
        args: [--config-file=.github/linters/.mypy.ini, mypackage]
```

It works when I run mypy directly: `mypy --config-file=.github/linters/.mypy.ini mypackage`

```
Success: no issues found in 23 source files
```

If have already tried the suggestions [here](https://github.com/pre-commit/mirrors-mypy/issues/5) but couldn't get it to work.

**EDIT 1**

When I remove the linting duplication by adopting `args: [--config-file=.github/linters/.mypy.ini]` I still get two types of errors

- source file found twice

```
tests\conftest.py: error: Source file found twice under different module names: "conftest" and "tests.conftest"
```

- Cannot find implementation or library stub for module (only for 3rd party imported modules), e.g.

```
mypackage\foo.py:1: error: Cannot find implementation or library stub for module named "uvicorn"  [import]
```

Answer (score 3):

pre-commit works by passing files to hooks -- you're double-linting the files by listing the package on the commandline *and* passing filenames -- simply remove your duplication:

```yaml
repos:
-   repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/mirrors-mypy
    rev: v1.3.0
    hooks:
    -   id: mypy
        args: [--config-file=.github/linters/.mypy.ini]
```

---

disclaimer: I wrote pre-commit

Comment: thanks though this introduces other issues, see edit 1 above

Comment: the first error above is solved by reading the issue you linked -- the second is solved by reading the README